# Is it possible to configure ms Unity container from an xml document and NOT from a file?

Tags: unity-container, containers, configure

Is it possible to configure ms Unity container from an xml document and NOT from a file?

Comment: This is a good question, could you edit it a bit to make it a bit clearer what you're trying to achieve (from your comments)

Comment: I think xaml would be a great idea, just like the Module Catalog of Prism that can be configured with XAML.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about that, but you can configure programmatically without a .config, so you could have your own xml file, read settings and programmatically setup your Unity container.  It's ashame this facet isn't covered in alot of the documentation.  There are alot of scenarios where the App.config isn't available or appropriate.

Edit:

> By default, this is the App.config or
>   Web.config file for your application.
>   However, you can load configuration
>   information from any other XML format
>   file or from other sources.

**See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440941.aspx**

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. What they show is in code, or from another file. I want to manage the configuration in sql and read the data into an xmldocument and then populate the container.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mistook "document" to mean file, didn't realize you meant a inmemory XmlDocument.  Closest you might get is reading it from SQL and configuring in code, without the XmlDocument.  Would be a pain though.  I'm searching to see if there are any methods for inmemory config files in general.

Comment: I wonder if you might be able to implement a ConfigurationManager class that allows for the use of an XmlDocument.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you save the XMLDocument in some file localy on the machine and then load that XML file in the Unity container.

Unless there is any restriction in saving the XMLdocument i think it would work.

Comment: This would work providing you either:  (a) never changed the configuration or (b) re-created the file every time.  Still, it's only a workaround:  DB->file->Unity isn't as nice as DB->Unity. (+1 because you said what I was thinking, though.)